# How to detect a memory leak?

Tags: c, macos, memory

I am pretty new to programming and I want to know how to detect a memory leak? If you are going to recommend a utility, please try to find one that works on Mac OS X Lion.

P.S. I tried valgrind, it doesn't work on 10.7/Lion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend [Instruments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruments_%28application%29) (which comes with Xcode). I admit I've never used it for C, but works well with Objective-C.

Comment: Valgrind [has some issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35964228/valgrind-and-pthreads-on-os-x-el-capitan-cant-make-a-smallest-working-exampl) with pthreads on a Mac running ~10.12.

Answer (score 4):

Valgrind is an excellent cross platform tool http://valgrind.org/

And best of all its Open Source

Answer (score 1):

valgrind - http://valgrind.org/ is pretty good

or mudflap - http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/HomePage 
but i'm not sure if mudflap works on Mac OS though ,it works on most the linux platform, you could try =)