# Finding Memory Allocation in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, memory, allocation

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Programmatically retrieve memory usage on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787160/programmatically-retrieve-memory-usage-on-iphone)
>   [How to detect a memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774684/how-to-detect-a-memory-leak)

Hey I want to know the memory allocation in my app programatically in iPhone SDK . Need Help.

Comment: http://www.voyce.com/index.php/2008/06/20/programmatically-checking-memory-usage/ It will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Apple has a tool called **[Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652)** for that:

[**Instruments** User Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652)

[iOS Developer Tools Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/URL_Tools_for_iPhone_OS_Development/_index.html)

Comment: well I have clearly written programmatically. Why you people  are referring me Instruments.?

Answer (score 1):

If you just run your application in Profile mode (click and hold the Run button and select Profile or do `Command-I`), it will open [Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) and you can choose to profile memory allocations from there.

Comment: well I have clearly written programmatically. Why you people are referring me Instruments.?

Comment: I actually originally added information for programmatically as well, but it was edited out when your question got closed.