# valgrind and pthreads (on os x El Capitan): can't make a smallest working example?

Tags: pthreads, valgrind

A pthreads program *seems* to work fine for me on El Capitan, but when I run with valgrind I get a SIGSEGV crash 'Access not within mapped region at address 0x700002F32C05' from within pthread_join.

The stacktrace differs slightly, based on whether I'm trying to access a return-value from the thread or not (ends in `_pthread_find_thread` vs `_OSSpinLockLockSlow`).

My question: Am I mis-understanding how to use pthreads, or is this a valgrind-on-Yosemite issue?  (Or, something else?)

I'm running valgrind 3.11, gcc clang-700.1.76 ('thread model: posix'), OS X 10.11.3.  (I see just now that valgrind says v3.11.0 is "preliminary support for El Capitan", so maybe that's the issue?)

```
==== version A ====
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *myThread() {
  int* retPtr = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *retPtr = 42;
  return (void*) retPtr;
  }

int main() {
   pthread_t tid;
   int *answer;

   pthread_create(&tid, NULL, myThread, NULL);
   pthread_join(tid, (void**)&answer);

   printf("%d\n", *answer);
   free((void*)answer);
   return 0;
}
```

==== Version B (EDIT: now pasted correctly) ====

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *myThread() { 
    return NULL;
    }

int main() {
    pthread_t tid;

    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, myThread, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);

    return 0;
    }
```

==== stack trace for version A: ====

```
==39520== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==39520==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x700002F32C3E
==39520==    at 0x10044437F: _pthread_find_thread (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==39520==    by 0x100446CE2: _pthread_lookup_thread (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==39520==    by 0x100446ABA: pthread_join (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==39520==    by 0x100000F27: main (hoo.c:15)
```

==== Stack trace for Version B: ====

```
==39528== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==39528==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x700002F32C05
==39528==    at 0x100432E2B: _OSSpinLockLockSlow (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib)
==39528==    by 0x100446B10: pthread_join (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==39528==    by 0x100000F57: main (hoo.c:14)
```

Comment: This program compiles and runs fine on my computer using  the -lpthread option during compilation. Also, running with valgrind produces no errors.

Comment: Also, A and B look identical. What is the difference between them?

Comment: Hi @TonyRuth -- sorry, B was indeed a mis-paste duplicate; it's fixed now.

Comment: @TonyRuth Thanks for the check that valgrind doesn't give errors on your system.  Bolsters my suspicion that it's a valgrind-on-el-capitan issue.

Comment: just double checking. You did use -lpthread during compilation right? On my computer I can compile the code without that flag, but not run it. Might do something different on yours. It needs both the header files and library linkage. The specific error message refers to a pointer out of bounds.

Comment: Yes, I can compile+link w/ and w/o the `-lpthread`, and get the same valgrind behavior either way.

Comment: I have had another person confirm that these programs passed `valgrind` on their system w/o any error.  (I will close this question soon, on the assumption that the problem is indeed due to valgrind-on-el-capitan-is-'preliminary'.)

Comment: I think the problem is with pthread and not Valgrind, but I'm not certain. https://bytecoin.org/blog/pthread-bug-osx/ reports a problem with pthread in recent versions of OSX relating to dropped memory. That agrees with Valgrind's assessment of a pointer set to an unallocated memory address.